# Exchange client puts signature before response

Tags: exchange, nexus-5

I have a nexus 5, and I use the built-in exchange client for handling my work e-mail. I've noticed that when I send a reply, my exchange server adds my signature, but it seems to add it on top of my response text, instead of like my normal e-mails where the signature is after the response text.

I've used Samsung's exchange client before and it ordered these two correctly, is there a way to do this on the Nexus 5?